# Should i use Data Access Object for each of my model?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, dao

Let's say i have a few objects that are linked together by association.
For Example, A Company Object and a Worker object.
A company will have multiple worker under them. A company will have an arrayList of WorkerObj as a reference list to the worker object.

During the useage of DAO, do i save the company object as a whole with the worker object encapsulated into it. Or do i save a company object and than save the arrayList of WorkerObj?(after that i'll retrieve them and join them together)

The main idea is to save each company using dao to a file and retrive them later with the same state.

Please forgive me if i did make any wrong question. Please guide me for my learning!

Comment: where do you want to save these objects? in a rdbms? that would be the simple approach. just create two tables and store the object's information there. then, when needed, this info can be read from the tables.

Comment: It's a generic question but good practice to have a DAO for each model object.  Then add a service that interacts with the DAO and your controller fetch one or the other (or both) as needed

Comment: If I were to retrieve the model individually, how do I attach the model together. As shown in the example, how do I attach the worker obj to the company?